# Is there a performance difference between null-check and null-conditional-operator in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, null-check, null-conditional-operator

I am wondering whether there is a difference in performance between these two if-statements:

```cs
if(myObject != null && myObject.someBoolean)
{
    // do something
}

if (myObject?.someBoolean ?? false)
{
    // do something
}
```

If there is a difference in performance, in favor of which approach and why?

**Edit:**
This is not a bottleneck in my application, I am not trying to over-optimize, I am simply curious.

Comment: *If* that location has actually been measured as a bottleneck in your application, *measure* both and choose the one that works best in your situation. You *cannot* optimize by learning a few (hundred/thousand/million) rules and then blindly applying them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That doesnt answer my question. This is not a bottleneck in my application, I am simply curious.

Comment: They are the same. The null-conditional operator is just syntactic sugar for `if(myObject != null && myObject.someBoolean)`

Comment: Whether you admit it or not, you're trying to learn to optimize by pattern matching and, quite simply, that *does not work*. Write the simplest, easiest to read code and don't sweat "best performance" until you actually need it.

Comment: The problem is that what is fastest in one particular situation, may not be fastest in a different situation. What is better, using + to concatenate strings, or use StringBuilder? Real answer: it depends. `"a" + "b"` is way faster than using StringBuilder

Answer (score 5):

When the code will be compiled, both if-statements will be the same. You can easily check it with [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/)

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the resource, that confirms my suspicion! I actually had a typo in my first if statment, it should have been `myObject != null`, otherwise both statements are different. I will correct it in the question.